# Android : shrinkResources is failing to build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, proguard, android-proguard

I m trying to use shrinkResources and its failing at the build time. I don't see any issue when I don't `shrinkResources`. I have following configurations:

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
```

gradle versions

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.3.3' 

and

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip
```

.

**I have also seen many people out here facing the same issue with some recommended solutions like:**

- turn on minifyEnabled true in order to use shrinkResources true, which I m already doing it.
- Some recommended to turn off shrink resource by shrinkResources false in order to build the app, but I need to use shrinkResources and so it doesn't apply to me.
- There were some recommendation/suggestions that gradle plugin has/had a bug, and I should use plugin version < 2.2, which I can't at this point of time.

Highly appreciate if someone from the community helps me out here.

Below is the log that I m seeing in the gradle console:

```
:app:transformClassesWithShrinkResForJenkinsRelease
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Failed to shrink resources: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.; ignoring
Failed to shrink resources: ignoring
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at com.android.utils.XmlUtils.parseDocument(XmlUtils.java:493)
    at com.android.utils.XmlUtils.parseDocument(XmlUtils.java:474)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer.recordResources(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:1177)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer.recordResources(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:1160)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer.analyze(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:276)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ShrinkResourcesTransform.transform(ShrinkResourcesTransform.java:209)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:185)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:181)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
:app:mergeJenkinsReleaseJniLibFolders
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForJenkinsRelease
:app:validateSigningJenkinsRelease
:app:packageJenkinsRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageJenkinsRelease'.
> File '/Users/rbc/Documents/GitLab/MyAPPName/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-jenkins-release-stripped.ap_' specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist.
```

.
.
Apart from this, if anyone think they need extra information to understand my scenario, please feel free to let me know and I will post the information as much as I could here in the question section.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue -

```
> Task :app:shrinkQaReleaseRes
[Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Premature end of file.
```

After some headscratching I realised that a previous git merge left an empty .xml file which was causing it to break.  I deleted the empty file and the task succeeds now.

Answer (score 1):

for me it is working fine. I am using

- [global build.gradle](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/blob/FDroid/build.gradle)

  - classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
  - // no special progruad inclusion
- [local app/build.gradle](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/blob/FDroid/app/build.gradle)

  - shrinkResources true
  - minifyEnabled true

In the [proguard-rules.pro](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/blob/FDroid/app/proguard-rules.pro) i have

```
###############
# I use proguard only to remove unused stuff and to keep the app small.
# I donot want to obfuscate (rename packages, classes, methods, ...) since this is open source
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
-keepnames class ** { *; }
-keepnames interface ** { *; }
-keepnames enum ** { *; }
```

I think i had problems before i added `-dontoptimize`

Comment: Thanks @k3b for the response, my gradle does contain -dontoptimize, but unfortunately its failing.

Comment: Thanks man. -dontoptimize did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

What saved me was to delete an empty file .xml file in android/app/src/main/res/xml

And here is my config in android/app/build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        multiDexEnabled true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        
    }
}
```

So basically it's a mixture of some different solutions I found online